# Artifacts in render (EEVEE)

Tags: artifacts

I rendered this image in Blender 2.81 Alpha.

[image]

The helmet has a simple glossy shader with roughness set to 0.265. I'm rendering this in Eevee. The blue is coming from a spotlight in the back. What is causing the lines to appear in the glossy reflection and how can I remove it?

**Things I have Tried**

- Cranking up the sampling numbers
- Remeshing
- Subdividing
- Applying all modifiers I have in modifier stack

I would love to provide more details if you need it.

Comment: Does it look bad in Cycles too? It's worth looking at your shadow settings in both the render tab & the light tab (need the light selected for the tab to appear), try soft shadows and/or high bit depth in the render tab for a start.

Comment: It does look better in cycles. I hadn't thought of messing with shadows and turns out it does make a big difference. Thanks! For the time being, I have cranked up the bloom to cover up these artifacts.

Comment: No sweat. I think of eevee as a scanline renderer on steroids: it can be good enough for production or whatever, but it’s a juggling act. It does shine with volumes though, where you can forgive the slight lack of quality for saving potentially days of render time!

Answer (score 1):

Increase minimum clip distance on camera. That should solve the problem. Explanation here:
https://devtalk.blender.org/t/why-eevee-with-zoom-up-cause-broken-mesh-for-layered-parts-solved/4098